# AsyncTask#1 an error occured while executing doInBackgroud

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I got this error whenever I change my URL to my online hosting, but if I change to 10.0.2.2 everything seems fine and running.

#### LogCat

```
02-01 23:02:18.302  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-01 23:02:18.303  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d8d9a8)
02-01 23:02:18.303  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: uncaught exception occurred
02-01 23:02:18.304  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-01 23:02:18.304  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-01 23:02:18.304  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-01 23:02:18.305  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-01 23:02:18.305  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-01 23:02:18.305  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-01 23:02:18.305  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-01 23:02:18.306  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-01 23:02:18.306  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
02-01 23:02:18.306  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 23:02:18.306  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at com.example.jithea.testlogin.NewsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(NewsActivity.java:132)
02-01 23:02:18.306  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at com.example.jithea.testlogin.NewsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(NewsActivity.java:107)
02-01 23:02:18.307  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-01 23:02:18.307  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-01 23:02:18.307  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/System.err﹕ ... 4 more
02-01 23:02:18.307  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
02-01 23:02:18.315  17643-18052/com.example.jithea.testlogin E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.jithea.testlogin.NewsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(NewsActivity.java:132)
            at com.example.jithea.testlogin.NewsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(NewsActivity.java:107)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
02-01 23:02:18.371  17643-17659/com.example.jithea.testlogin I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x528dc150) fps:43.08, dur:1044.57, max:73.51, min:6.02
```

And here's my `NewsActivity.java`

```
public class NewsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParserNews jParser = new JSONParserNews();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://agustiniancampusevents.site40.net/newsDB/get_all_news.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_NEWS = "news";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NEWSTITLE = "newstitle";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ViewNewsActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_NEWS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String newstitle = c.getString(TAG_NEWSTITLE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NEWSTITLE, newstitle);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ViewNewsActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            NewsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.news_list_item, new String[]{TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NEWSTITLE},
                            new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.newstitle});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your server side is not working, it show error or warning instead of JSON format, so your code crashes